# AudioQueue Output Callback only fires 3 times (nBuffers times)

Tags: iphone, audioqueue

When I start an audio output process with `AudioQueueStart(out.queue, nil)`, the output callback only fires 3 times (which is the number of allocated buffers).

Here is my Output callback code:

```
static void AQOutputCallback(void* aqr,
                             AudioQueueRef outQ,
                             AudioQueueBufferRef outQB)
{
  AQCallbackStruct *aqc = (AQCallbackStruct *) aqr;

  NSLog(@"Out");

  // Check if AudioQueue is stopped
  if (!aqc->run) {
    NSLog(@"Stopped");
    return;
  }

  // Processing data

  // Check enqueue error
  int err = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(outQ, outQB, 0, NULL);
  if (err != noErr) NSLog(@"OutputCallback AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer() %d ", err);
  NSLog(@"Enqueued");
}
```

I think it's due to the lack of buffers, but my output is:

```
Out
Enqueued
Out
Enqueued
Out
Enqueued
```

So the first buffer is enqueued before the AudioQueue starts to fill the third one, it should not run out of buffers.

What happens here ?

### Edit: Setup code

```
#define AUDIO_BUFFERS 3

typedef struct AQCallbackStruct {
  AudioStreamBasicDescription mDataFormat;
  AudioQueueRef queue;
  AudioQueueBufferRef mBuffers[AUDIO_BUFFERS];
  unsigned long frameSize;
  BOOL *run;
} AQCallbackStruct;

// In some method
AQCallbackStruct out;

out.mDataFormat
out.mDataFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
out.mDataFormat.mSampleRate = 44100.0;
out.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
out.mDataFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
out.mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket =
  out.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame =
    out.mDataFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(short int);
out.mDataFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
out.mDataFormat.mFormatFlags =
    kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian
  | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger
  | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;

out.frameSize = 735;

int err;
err = AudioQueueNewOutput(&out.mDataFormat,
                          AQOutputCallback,
                          &out,
                          CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),
                          kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                          0,
                          &out.queue);

if (err != noErr) NSLog(@"AudioQueueNewOutput() error: %d", err);


for (int i=0; i<AUDIO_BUFFERS; i++) {         
  err = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(out.queue, out.frameSize, &out.mBuffers[i]);
  if (err != noErr) NSLog(@"Output AudioQueueAllocateBuffer() error: %d", err);
  out.mBuffers[i]->mAudioDataByteSize = out.frameSize;

  err = AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(out.queue, out.mBuffers[i], 0, NULL);
  if (err != noErr) NSLog(@"Output AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer() error: %d", err);
}

AudioQueueStart(out.queue, nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out where the problem was: [AudioQueue callback in simulator but not on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218335/audioqueue-callback-in-simulator-but-not-on-device/)

However, the output callback was properly fired in simulator but not on my device, and I still don't know exactly why there are differences in the AudioSession settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this page: [where to start with audio synthesis on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067267/where-to-start-with-audio-synthesis-on-iphone).

The BleepMachine sample code that's in there is what got me started with this.

Comment: Does it, in any way, solve my problem here ? I'm talking about running out of buffers, not about starting with audio synthesis...

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info then? What is it that you are trying to accomplish, if not audio synth? Could it be that you are not doing the setup correctly; what setup code are you using?

Comment: I updated my question with the setup code. I'm just trying to output something to my iPhone speaker, but I don't think its relevant here, as it doesn't work even without sound processing code.

Comment: I looked at the initialization code you added. I see two differences with mine, not sure how relevant they are:
(1) In the call to AudioQueueNewOutput, I pass NULL instead of CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), and
(2) In the call to AudioQueueAllocateBuffer, in the second parameter (the size) I pass what would be in your code: frameSize*out.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame (because what you call 'frameSize' I took to be the number of frames in the buffer)

Comment: I tried to put `NULL` instead of `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()`, and `frameSize*out.mDataFormat.mBytesPerFrame` during buffer allocation, but it changes nothing. I'm stuck :(